# Overlay Not Covering Entire Header

Tags: html, css, background, position, overlay

I'm not really sure how to word this question but I'll try.
So, I'm trying to get an overlay over the top of a background image, the header itself is taking up 100vh, but when I place the overlay with the image included, some padding from the nav is pushing the background colour down below the viewport it seems. I've tried to take margin off the nav elements and it brings the background up a little but not all the way. Maybe I'm missing something very simple here but I just can't seem to get my head around it.

Here's a link to the codepen (I know the code is a bit of a mess, it's just a test): https://codepen.io/Jmp93/pen/BMJwov

```
<nav id="main-nav">
    <h3>TEST|Web</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <header>
    <h1>Test Text Sample</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sunt dolores, dolorum minima id beatae aperiam saepe
      sapiente animi quas earum?</p>
  </header>

  <section id="start-section">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="m-heading">Some Text</h1>
      <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta possimus dolore temporibus aut,
        reiciendis voluptatum voluptate consequatur ducimus. Sunt minus nihil nulla in commodi. In officiis, harum amet
        eos nesciunt illum rerum aliquam quasi modi natus quis laudantium qui quae?</p>
    </div>
  </section>
```

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.m-heading {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: .75rem;
}

.lead {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
}

header:before {
  content: '';
  background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature,water') no-repeat center center/cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.2;
  z-index: -1;
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
  margin: 1rem;
}

#main-nav {
  display: flex;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#main-nav h3 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 2rem;
}

#main-nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-items: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin: 2rem;
}

#main-nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

#main-nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1rem;
}

#main-nav ul li a:hover {
  background: #444;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2rem;
}

#start-section {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to apply a position relative to the header itself :) usually if you use a position absolute, the main element containing it should be relative. That is the correct way of making the absolute element be positioned at 100% of its parent's width and height and not floating without reference.

Comment: Hi, I did try that but then it seems to have the opposite effect in that it pushes the background and overlay down, causing the same problem but at the top instead of the bottom! Not sure why this is happening still..

Thanks a lot for answering!

Comment: If I see the same you are seeing, that happens because the header starts right after the nav. So, and as it is a before pseudo element, it is covering the whole header, it is just not covering the navbar area. So what I would suggest, even though I am not a fan of negative margins: give your main navbar a height and then attribute to the header a margin-top: -yournavbarheight. Keep the position relative on the header. Hope it works :)

Comment: I just figured out it was the nav just before reading this, and thank you for the solution, it worked perfectly! However, is there another solution that doesn't require negative margin? Or would that be the most sensible way of resolving it in this case?

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Actually no need for another solution, this one does the job perfectly. Thanks again for your help! :)

Comment: I think I would insert the navbar inside the header, so that the background could cover both areas. Actually I think that semantically it makes sense to be like this. You can try it to see if it turns out as you want. No problem, I am glad it worked!